# SQL BETWEEN not returning expected results

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database with a few tables. A table called `Packages` has a column called `DateIn`.

Here's the SQL statement I'm executing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Packages] 
WHERE DateIn BETWEEN '01-06-2020' AND '01-07-2020'
```

I'm expecting all packages which have a `DateIn` between 1st of June and 1st of July 2020. I have 2 sample packages in the table: one has a `DateIn` value of '21-06-2020' and the other '27-06-2020'.

If I change the query to this it works and returns both packages:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Packages] 
WHERE DateIn BETWEEN '01-06-2020' AND '30-06-2020'
```

As you can see the day value is between 01 and 30 in this case. I'm saving the date in dd-mm-yyyy format.

The data type of `DateIn` is `nvarchar(50)` instead of `date` because the app sets it to "N/A" where necessary.

I think the issue may be the fact that the data type is `nvarchar(50)` instead of `date` but I can't use that for the reason stated above. Is there a way to do this where I can keep `nvarchar(50)`?

Comment: As you said: "I think the issue may be the fact that the data type is `nvarchar(50)` instead of `date`". The way comparison operations are performed is determined by the data type. A date stored as a string is **just a string** and will be compared as such. If you insist on storing dates as strings (for technical or other reasons) then you need to convert and sanitise your string dates to real dates (`datetime`) in your query. Try [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function.

Comment: Don't store dates as a string, and use the ISO format: "YYYY-MM-DD". Use NULL or another column for your N/A types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to Alex's answer, if you are able to get it to a Date value, beware that BETWEEN can have some unanticipated consequences. Aaron Bertrand outlines them very nicely at https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

In your example, using 30-06-2020 as an end date for Between can cause SQL to omit an entire days' worth of data.

Comment: Thanks to Owen West and @Alex. TRY_CONVERT was what I needed. Thanks for everyone else's comments. Hope this helps out someone.